# Check user on every page using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux

In my `App.tsx` file I have this setup

```
const App: React.FC = props => {
  const [hasRendered, setHasRendered] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isAuth = authMiddleWare();

  useEffect(() => setHasRendered(true), [hasRendered]);

  if (!hasRendered && isAuth !== null) {
    if (isAuth) {
      dispatch(getUser());
    } else {
      dispatch(logoutUser());
    }
  }
  ...
  <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={Dashboard} />
}

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, location, ...rest }: any) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const authenticated = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.authenticated);

  return <>{authenticated ? React.createElement(component, props) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: LoginRoute, state: { from: props.location } }} </>;
};
```

However, authentication only gets executed on browser reload, so data is not updated if I click a link within my app. I want the user to be checked when loading any private route.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate auth component and call it in every route and check the user is authenticated or not.
if the user authenticated then requested route show else return the 404page or homepage.

or check in every page you can check your authentication by putting this code in componentditmount section

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { userLoginAction } from "./store/actions/userLogin";
import * as actionType from "./store/actions/actionType";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class componentName extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            isMount:false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token != null && this.props.loginStatus === false) {
      // this.userLoginData(token)
      this.props.auth();
    }
    this.setState({ isMount: true });
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      {this.state.isMount?this.props.auth===false?<Redirect from ='/' to='/login' />:
     <p>Hello World!</p> :<div>Loging.....</div>
      }

      </>
    )
  }
}

const mapGetState = (state) => {
    return {
      loginStatus: state.usrReducer.login_st,
      auth: state.usrReducer.auth,
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchState = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      login: (data) => dispatch({ type: actionType.LOGIN_ST, payload: data }),
      auth: (data) => dispatch(userLoginAction(data)),
    };
  };
  export default connect(mapGetState, mapDispatchState)(componentName)
```